# How to set border for a highcharts pie?

Tags: highcharts

I want to set a border for a pie,but when there is no data the pie become this
[image]

How to realize it?

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the load event, check series.data length and if its empty, then use renderer to add empty circle.

```
chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie',
            events:{
                load: function() {
              var chart = this,
                    series = chart.series[0],
                  center = series.center;

                    if(series.data.length === 0) {
                    chart.renderer.circle(center[0],center[1],100)
                    .attr({
                        fill:'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                      stroke: 'red',
                      'stroke-width': 1
                    })
                    .add();

                  }
              }
            }
        },
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/u6tax8x4/

Answer (score 0):

Pie with default border stroke will show up in the newest versions. I guess it is just the versioning issue here.

Please update the highcharts to latest version here : https://code.highcharts.com/zips/Highcharts-8.0.0.zip